# How can I get Number of Threads and Duration from CSV in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I can easily get username and password from CSV using CSV config control in Jmeter but I can't do same for Number of Threads & Duration for Thread Group.

I tried and provided Number of Threads and duration in CSV but seems not working. Getting Number of Threads always Zero.

Is there any way to get it? Just want to make my JMX dynamic so no need to open JMX if I only want to change number of threads and duration and can be easily update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is to parameterize the number of threads and duration. But should it be from CSV file by using `CSV config element`? Because We can not do that way!

One suggestion is to keep a properties file for thread numbers and duration for each Thread Group and pass the properties file as parameter.

This is exactly explained here with more additional information as well.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-manage-test-plan/